# Import CSV in batches of lines in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I'm using FasterCSV to import an uploaded file to a model, and it's working great for small files. However when I try to import a large dataset (21,000 lines) it takes ages and I get browser timeouts on the live server.

This is my current working code:

```
  logcount=0
  Attendee.transaction do
    FCSV.new(file, :headers => true).each do |row|
      row[1] = Date.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%Y')
      record = @event.attendees.new(:union_id => row[0], :dob => row[1], :gender => row[2])
      if record.save
        logcount += 1
      end
    end
  end
```

I'd love to use a background process, but the user needs to see how many lines were imported before they can move to the next step of the system.

So, I was thinking that I should use [action chunking](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=ddmqwkxs_3972nphr5fk) and only read a smaller number of lines, set a counter, then update the view with some kind of progress, then run the method again using the previous counter as start point.

I can't seem to see how to get FasterCSV to read only a set number of lines, and also set an offset for the start point.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [AR Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)

**Old answer**

Have you tried to use [AR Extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions) for bulk import?
You get impressive performance improvements when you are inserting 1000's of rows to DB.
Visit their [website](http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext) for more details.

Comment: For anyone looking at this dead link: https://web.archive.org/web/20080729041651/http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext

Comment: This solution is no longer valid for Rails 3 and above. There's a gem now from the same team of devs in: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: @tommyalvarez Updated the answer. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather create a prepared query, load a line from the file and execute the prepared query. Without any use of the model, should be faster.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean?  And do you think it'd be fast enough not to need to send updates to the browser?

Comment: Not with 21000 records to import.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the database why not import it through a Rake Task? Are your users going to be importing such large databases?

If your users are going to be importing such large database a task won't do.

FCSV.new can take any options IO.open can. You can use that to seek to a particular byte. Unfortunately FCSV doesn't make it easy to stop or access the underlying IO object, to find out where you stopped. Resuming in the middle of a file also complicates the use of a header row.

Really, I think the optimal solution is to outsource your CSV import to a drb, that periodically reports it's progress in a way the controller action can pick up on. Then call that controller action every so often with some AJAX running on the client.

I've had success with [BackgroundDRb](http://brainspl.at/articles/2006/05/15/backgoundrb-initial-release) in the past. It's installation and use is a little too detailed for me to reproduce here. There are other plugins and gems available with a bit of googling.

**DRb Caveat** Most DRb solutions require an additional daemon process running on your server. some webhosts forbid this on more basic plans. Check your TOS