# Ruby fastcsv import russian words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I'm importing big csv file into my rails app, but i have trouble with that, that in my file i have some russian words. I't throw me utf8 error, i tried write:

```
CSV.foreach("/#{Rails.public_path}/uploads/hshatem2.csv", {:encoding => 'ISO-8859-15:UTF-8', :col_sep => ';', :row_sep => :auto, :headers => :first_row}) do | row |
```

But then it took i part of time too (i think for encoding). Also it think about 5 hours, without encoding it would be faster, but how to do this? How to don't read russian words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). CSV is not bad for smaller CSV files but gets bogged down on larger. Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579567/import-csv-in-batches-of-lines-in-rails) on importing larger files that may help.

Additionally you might want to break out the load and iteration into two steps. So do a CSV.parse for the file and then iterate over the rows.

Comment: don;t understand "Additionally you might want to break out the load and iteration into two steps. So do a CSV.parse for the file and then iterate over the rows."

Comment: Do something like `@file = CSV.parse(file)` [I forget the exact syntax] and then `@file.CSVRows.each do |blah|`. You could push that to another thread even.